# Removable dvd-station does work in Windows 8.1, does not in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: vlc, dvd

I used (see https://itsfoss.com/play-dvd-ubuntu-1310/) the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse  (already installed)
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

Result: dvd-station gives a connect c.q. disconnect tone, but is not visible in bottom left corner; dvd files are nowhere to be found.
I use the VLC Media player.

Regards,
JGF

Comment: Try also installing `libdvdread7` and `libdvdnav4` as those are not included in the `libdvd-pkg`.  `sudo apt install libdvdread7 libdvdnav4`

Comment: @Terrance  Thanks for your advice! Unfortunately the two extra commands didn't work... Would there be any software I can install? Funny thing is that the removable player works fine with Windows.  Regards, JGF

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what do you mean it didn't work?  There is only one command I gave you there and that is to install the packages that are needed to READ and NAVIGATE DVDs.  The command is `sudo apt install libdvdread7 libdvdnav4` then you probably need to reboot after installation.

Comment: I wasn't quite specific indeed.  I applied **sudo apt install libdvdread7 libdvdnav4**  and rebooted. With **sudo lshw -C disk** I see the drivers are properly installed. So far so good. However I don't see my VLC player appearing. When I load a DVD I do get a sign that it can be opened in files. I see/hear a flash of a beginning, then nothing. The same sign tells me to open in Terminal, where I read **fre@ubuntu-260121:/media/fre/UNA_GIORNATA_PARTICOLARE$**  The DVD is properly loaded, but how can I get it to play?

Comment: In VLC I have found that if I choose just the disc it doesn't work correctly, but if I open the disc through Media -> Open Disc -> Browse then it has worked every time for me.

Comment: ![Una giornata...2_ 2021-05-25 09-01-26.png] After `Media -> Open Disc -> Browse` VLC shows an opening screen with three choices: -**Start film -Chapters -Subtitles**.  The upper fifth part of the image is covered by a light green band.  VLC plays a repeating introduction tune. Regardless which choice out of three I make VLC shuts down. (Sorry: the link to the screenshot doesn't work)